# call web config value in javascript src google map api

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, google-maps-api-3, jscript.net

I am having a problem with the javascript accessing the webconfig file and here's my javascript side...

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleAPIKey"]%>"></script>
```

accessing the webconfig but I am receiving an error...

here's the
web.config

```
<add key="GoogleAPIKey" value="key api"/>
```

Your helping hand is higly appreciated..

Comment: @Div I tried this the same error   Literal expressions like '<%$ ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["GoogleAPIKey"] %>' are not allowed.

Comment: @Div I did that already if you will check my script above. Thanks

Comment: @Div yes same error.  Literal expressions like '<%$ ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleAPIKey"] %>' are not allowed

Comment: OK, Why do you want like this?

Comment: @Div For portability purposes....

Comment: Are you worried about people "stealing" your key?

Comment: @Div Nope this will be deployed on different  servers with different keys. The logic is that you don't have to recompile the source code every time you change the key. Thanks

Comment: Jake, I created sample of code at my side and it's working properly.

Comment: @Div would you paste it here if possible?

Comment: @Jake Marmak: What kind of error do you receive?

Comment: @Evgeny Gorb - Literal expression are not allowed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my Solution to my problem..

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="LitGoogle" />" ></script>
```